# Exchange Online - EWS API - removing calendar items

Tags: powershell, calendar, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Outlook , I want to remove the 'Old Calendar' items.

My workflow is :

- to clear out the items in each calendar first then confirm it was empty and delete it.

But , I have checked below line. But `$oFindFolderResults` is null.

```
$oFindFolderResults = $service.FindFolders([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::MsgFolderRoot,$oSearchFilter,$oFolderView)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will always bind to the Mailbox of the Security credentials your using because you haven't included any impersonation code if that's what you want to use (your code comments indicate this) or if you want to use delegate access you need to use the FolderId overload.

For impersonation you need to add

```
$service.ImpersonatedUserId = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ImpersonatedUserId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ConnectingIdType]::SmtpAddress, $MailboxName)
```

Also add the Anchor mailbox header eg

```
$service.HttpHeaders.Add("X-AnchorMailbox", $MailboxName);
```

For delegation or even with impersonation i would use

```
    $folderid = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Root, $MailboxName)   
    $oFindFolderResults = $service.FindFolders($folderid,$oSearchFilter,$oFolderView)
```

That will ensure your always searching the Mailbox in the $MailboxName variable

for deleting items try something like (where $Calendar is you target folder)

```html
$ivItemView = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemView(1000)  
$fiResult = ""  
do{  
    $fiResult = $Calendar.FindItems($ivItemView)  
    $type = ("System.Collections.Generic.List" + '`' + "1") -as "Type"
    $type = $type.MakeGenericType("Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemId" -as "Type")
    $Itemids = [Activator]::CreateInstance($type)
    "Delete " + $fiResult.Items.Count + " Items"  
    foreach($Item in $fiResult.Items){  
        $Itemids.Add($Item.Id)  
    }  
    #Delete the Items  
    $Result = $service.DeleteItems($Itemids,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.DeleteMode]::SoftDelete,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SendCancellationsMode]::SendToNone,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.AffectedTaskOccurrence]::AllOccurrences)  
    [INT]$Rcount = 0  
    foreach ($res in $Result){  
        if ($res.Result -eq [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResult]::Success){  
            $Rcount++  
        }  
    }  
    $Rcount.ToString() + " Items deleted successfully"  
    $ivItemView.offset += $fiResult.Items.Count  
}while($fiResult.MoreAvailable -eq $true)
```

Comment: If you remove the Search Filter what does it show do you see the folder from the target mailbox ? eg $oFindFolderResults = $service.FindFolders($folderid,$oFolderView)

Comment: Probably start your search at MsgfolderRoot at well

Comment: Your question doesn't make that much sense to me now as I said change you start folder to MsgFolderRoot which will make sure you just get mostly User created folders and then enumerate the entire Folder collection results  and see if the folder is in there

Comment: Is that your full folder output eg your missing Inbox, SentItems,drafts etc, is your question you can't see the folder in question now or you can ?

Comment: I think your initial question is solved eg I can see 'Old Calendar 1' in your output, what have you tried next?

Comment: And what code are you trying to use to do that ? (eg the empty method on the folder?)  what research have you done and what errors are you experiencing?

Comment: I updated the sample just note if you deleting more then 1000 items then you should break the batch or it may have issues with throttling

Comment: Look at the error message remove the call to Empty folder

Comment: Did you try removing that line?

Comment: $folder.Delete([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.DeleteMode]::SoftDelete)